# invertible matrix is a square matrix

Tags: matrices

If an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ has both left inverse and right inverse, then the given matrix is square and invertible.
I am done with $A$ is invertible but how to prove that $A$ is a square matrix?

Comment: only square matrices are called invertible(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix)

Comment: but here A is not square  i need to prove m = n, but how?

Comment: Note that in the case that $m\neq n$ then $rank(A)\leq \min(m,n)<\max(m,n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an $m\times n$ matrix has more rows than columns, i.e. $m>n$, then all the rows are in the same $n$-dimensional space, so no more than $n$ of them can be linearly independent.  But there are more than $n$ of them.  Thus the row of $n$ zeros can be written as a linear combination of them in more than one way.  Those two different linear combinations that evaluate to zero are two vectors getting mapped to the same image; hence that mapping is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B\in M_{n,m}(\Bbb F) $ and $C\in M_{n,m}(\Bbb F) $ are the left and right inverse of $A$ respectively. Then

$$C=(BA)C=B(AC)=B$$
so $I_n=BA=AB=I_m$ and then $m=n$.

Comment: $I_n = BA$, and $AB = I_m$. Okay. But where did $BA = AB$ come from?