# Find a matrix such that $XX'= I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are both $n \times k$ matrices with $n > k$.

Are there any matrices that satisfy $YX' = I_n$?

Comment: Why did you suppose there is a $X$ matrix?

Comment: Sadly, no there are not.  The rank of product $YX'$ is at most the rank of $X'$, which is at most $k\lt n$, while $I_n$ has rank $n$.  This has been brought out in many previous Questions.

Comment: Title and question do not match.

Comment: If $X'$ means transpose a matrix having orthonormal rows will have the property that $XX'=I$

Comment: See for example [Inverse of non-square matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098824/inverse-of-non-square-matrix) and [invertible matrix is a square matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889344/invertible-matrix-is-a-square-matrix), as well as [this Question about rank of a product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope).

Answer (score 0):

The rank of $YX'$ is less than the rank of $Y$ and the rank of $X$, both of which are at most $k$.  The identity has rank $n >k$ which would violate $YX' = I$.